# How to retrieve posts of user after he logged out from FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to figure out a core concept in FB that even after reading a lot of FB documentation, couldn't understand.
Let's say I'm building an app (that will reside in a tab), in which I want to see the last post of a user. I want to do this approximately one month after the user approved my app, without him using the app again.

I assume I will need to use a long-lived expiration token that will be saved to my DB.
A month after I will run a procedure that will use this token and check the user posts.

Is this correct?
What about a situation in which the user logged out? The token is no longer valid.. does this mean I will never be able to access user posts unless he will access my app?
Isn't this a bit weird (since he already approved my app)?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

Firstly, you need the `read_stream` permission from the user when they authenticate your app. Then, because you are intending to use Facebook as the app, rather than as the user, you need to authenticate as an app, which is a simple process:

In order to get an access token for the app, all you need to do is use the following URL:
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

Because these tokens are time-limited, it may be easier to request a token each time you use the Graph API, rather than storing it in a database and waiting for it to expire.

Then, all you need to do is use the following request:
`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

The upside to this is that it does not matter whether or not the user is logged into Facebook.

See here for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: Thanks but according to this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/
I will not be able to read posts, only publish on behalf of the user.